# Embedding IWebbrowser2 ATL interface control in C# windows mobile smart device application

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, webbrowser-control, smartphone

We have developed an ATL smart device project for to save the web page locally in windows mobile device. The application uses native IWebbrowser2 ATL interface control to browse the web page and save the web page complete.

Now we need to have our UI and other user interface controls to be designed and developed using C#  also we have some UI module already available in C#.

So please provide us a method to embed native IWebbrowser2 ATL interface control to the C# smart device project.

Comment: Just curious why you selected to use the IWebbrowser2 COM component over the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a COM component, you would follow the same methodology of any other COM component by writing a wrapper for it.  [MSDN has an article covering it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx).

Comment: After following the method to Host the ActiveX Web Browser (webvw.idl) control in C#, we are struck in getting webview.dll file from the mobile device.
 
to create a complete class definition by using  AxImp.exe we are unable to get the webview.dll from the device, now how shall we proceed further,

Please help.

Thanks,
Ramanand.

Comment: ask this as a separate question